# How to properly update the weights in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, gradient

I'm trying to implement the gradient descent with PyTorch according to this [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXFUe.png) but can't figure out how to properly update the weights. It is just a toy example with 2 linear layers with 2 nodes in hidden layer and one output.

```
Learning rate = 0.05;
target output = 1
```

https://hmkcode.github.io/ai/backpropagation-step-by-step/

[Forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXFUe.png)

[Backward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIUvZ.png)

My code is as following:

```
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    import torch.optim as optim

    class MyNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
         super(MyNet, self).__init__()
         self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 2,  bias=None)
         self.linear1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.11, 0.21], [0.12, 0.08]]))
         self.linear2 = nn.Linear(2, 1,  bias=None)
         self.linear2.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.14, 0.15]]))

    def forward(self, inputs):
         out = self.linear1(inputs)
         out = self.linear2(out)
         return out

    losses = []
    loss_function = nn.L1Loss()
    model = MyNet()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)
    input = torch.tensor([2.0,3.0])
    print('weights before backpropagation = ',   list(model.parameters()))
    for epoch in range(1):
       result = model(input )
       loss = loss_function(result , torch.tensor([1.00],dtype=torch.float))
       print('result = ', result)
       print("loss = ",   loss)
       model.zero_grad()
       loss.backward()
       print('gradients =', [x.grad.data  for x in model.parameters()] )
       optimizer.step()
       print('weights after backpropagation = ',   list(model.parameters()))
```

The result is following :

```
    weights before backpropagation =  [Parameter containing:
    tensor([[0.1100, 0.2100],
            [0.1200, 0.0800]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
    tensor([[0.1400, 0.1500]], requires_grad=True)]

    result =  tensor([0.1910], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward3>)
    loss =  tensor(0.8090, grad_fn=<L1LossBackward>)

    gradients = [tensor([[-0.2800, -0.4200], [-0.3000, -0.4500]]), 
                 tensor([[-0.8500, -0.4800]])]

    weights after backpropagation =  [Parameter containing:
    tensor([[0.1240, 0.2310],
            [0.1350, 0.1025]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
    tensor([[0.1825, 0.1740]], requires_grad=True)]
```

**Forward pass** values:

```
2x0.11 + 3*0.21=0.85 ->  
2x0.12 + 3*0.08=0.48 -> 0.85x0.14 + 0.48*0.15=0.191 -> loss =0.191-1 = -0.809
```

**Backward pass**: let's calculate w5 and w6 (output node weights)

```
w = w - (prediction-target)x(gradient)x(output of previous node)x(learning rate)  
w5= 0.14 -(0.191-1)*1*0.85*0.05= 0.14 + 0.034= 0.174  
w6= 0.15 -(0.191-1)*1*0.48*0.05= 0.15 + 0.019= 0.169
```

In my example Torch doesn't multiply the loss by derivative so we get wrong weights after updating. For the output node we got new weights w5,w6 [0.1825, 0.1740] , when it should be [0.174, 0.169]

Moving backward to update the first weight of the output node (w5) we need to calculate: `(prediction-target)x(gradient)x(output of previous node)x(learning rate)=-0.809*1*0.85*0.05=-0.034`. Updated weight `w5 = 0.14-(-0.034)=0.174`. But instead pytorch calculated `new weight = 0.1825`. It forgot to multiply by `(prediction-target)=-0.809`. For the output node we got gradients -0.8500 and -0.4800. But we still need to multiply them by loss 0.809 and learning rate 0.05 before we can update the weights.

What is the proper way of doing this?
Should we pass 'loss' as an argument to `backward()` as following: `loss.backward(loss)` .

That seems to fix it. But I couldn't find any example on this in documentation.

Comment: You should do `loss.zero_grad()` instead of `model.zero_grad()`. This is because the gradients accumulate (add up) when you do `loss.backward()`, so you should zero out those before taking another `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()`.

Comment: Actually loss.zero_grad() gives me  error. 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'zero_grad'.  In the pytorch tutorial  they use  model.zero_grad().  https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-nlp-word-embeddings-tutorial-py  But my question is why my model doesn't calculate  new weights properly when I do  loss.backward() and optimizer.step()

Comment: Yeah, sorry, `optimizer.zero_grad()` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.zero_grad()` with optimizer, so `optimizer.zero_grad()`, not loss or model as suggested in the comments (though model is fine, but it is not clear or readable IMO).

Except that your parameters are updated fine, so the error is not on PyTorch's side.

Based on gradient values you provided:

```
gradients = [tensor([[-0.2800, -0.4200], [-0.3000, -0.4500]]), 
             tensor([[-0.8500, -0.4800]])]
```

Let's multiply all of them by your learning rate (0.05):

```
gradients_times_lr = [tensor([[-0.014, -0.021], [-0.015, -0.0225]]), 
                      tensor([[-0.0425, -0.024]])]
```

Finally, let's apply ordinary SGD (theta -= gradient * lr), to get exactly the same results as in PyTorch:

```
parameters = [tensor([[0.1240, 0.2310], [0.1350, 0.1025]]),
              tensor([[0.1825, 0.1740]])]
```

What you have done is taken the gradients calculated by PyTorch and multiplied them with the output of previous node and **that's not how it works!**.

**What you've done:**

```
w5= 0.14 -(0.191-1)*1*0.85*0.05= 0.14 + 0.034= 0.174
```

**What should of been done (using PyTorch's results):**

```
w5 = 0.14 - (-0.85*0.05) = 0.1825
```

No multiplication of previous node, it's done behind the scenes (that's what `.backprop()` does - calculates **correct** gradients for all of the nodes), no need to multiply them by previous ones.

If you want to calculate them manually, you have to start at the loss (with delta being one) and backprop all the way down (**do not use learning rate here, it's a different story!**).

After all of them are calculated, you can multiply each weight by optimizers learning rate (or any other formula for that matter, e.g. Momentum) and after this you have your correct update.

## How to calculate backprop

Learning rate **is not** part of backpropagation, leave it alone until you calculate all of the gradients (it confuses separate algorithms together, optimization procedures and backpropagation).

### 1. Derivative of total error w.r.t. output

Well, I don't know why you are using **Mean Absolute Error** (while in the tutorial it is **Mean Squared Error**), and that's why both those results vary. But let's go with your choice.

**Derivative of | y_true - y_pred | w.r.t. to y_pred is 1**, so **IT IS NOT** the same as loss. Change to **MSE** to get equal results (here, the derivative will be (1/2 * y_pred - y_true), but we usually multiply MSE by two in order to remove the first multiplication).

In **MSE** case you would multiply by the loss value, but it depends entirely on the loss function (it was a bit unfortunate that the tutorial you were using didn't point this out).

### 2. Derivative of total error w.r.t. w5

You could probably go from here, but... Derivative of total error w.r.t to w5 is the output of h1 (0.85 in this case). We multiply it by derivative of total error w.r.t. output (it is 1!) and obtain 0.85, as done in PyTorch. Same idea goes for w6.

I seriously advise you **not to** confuse learning rate with backprop, you are making your life harder (and it's not easy with backprop IMO, quite counterintuitive), and those are two separate things (can't stress that one enough).

[This](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/) source is nice, more step-by-step, with a little more complicated network idea (activations included), so you can get a better grasp if you go through all of it.

Furthermore, if you are really keen (and you seem to be), to know more ins and outs of this, calculate the weight corrections for other optimizers (say, nesterov), so you know why we should keep those ideas separated.

Comment: Then how are we supposed to apply delta rule here?  What Pytorch did when updating the weight   is w5 = 0.14 - (-0.85*0.05) = 0.1825 ( 0.85 is the output of previous node), but we are missing delta  here (prediction - target), that is (0.191-1) .  According to delta rule it should be: w = w - (prediction-target)x(gradient)x(output of previous node)x(learning rate)

Comment: so correct weight should be calculated as:  w5= 0.14 -(0.191-1)*1*0.85*0.05= 0.14 + 0.034= 0.174 .  It is also according this tutorial 
 https://hmkcode.github.io/ai/backpropagation-step-by-step/

Comment: Edit went down, I missed your `L1Loss` part and was pretty confused as well, does it clear the confusion?

Comment: loss_function = nn.L1Loss().    It calculates the  loss correctly.  0.809 = 1 - 0.191.  But the loss is not applied when calculating the gradient.

Comment: You are confusing gradient of loss with loss. You use loss's gradient, not the output value. In MSE case it is y_pred - y_true (derivative of 1/2 * (y_pred - y_true)^2), but in MAE it is equal to 1 (y_pred - y_true, derivative of y_pred w.r.t. y_pred is 1 and derivative of y_true w.r.t. y_pred is 0) as provided in the answer.

Comment: So what should we do or how to correct the code so to get the right model  according to the tutorial  in https://hmkcode.github.io/ai/backpropagation-step-by-step/  ?  Surely I missed something. The model clearly doesn't apply delta rule

Comment: It does everything correctly, but your loss function is different. I seriously, once again, advise you to check the link in the provided answer. If you want the same weights & gradients as in your tutorial (once again, you might want to leave it and check the link instead), use [this loss function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss). Oh, if you could accept the answer I would be grateful, as it solves your issue.

Comment: thanks, it helped. In fact I tried to implement yesterday that example in the link you provided and It worked  fine.  So in my example the solution would be: loss_function = nn.MSELoss()  and  loss = loss_function(result , torch.tensor([1.00]))/2