# Pytorch: Custom thresholding activation function - gradient

Tags: pytorch, gradient, activation

I created an activation function class `Threshold` that should operate on one-hot-encoded image tensors.

The function performs min-max feature scaling on each channel followed by thresholding.

```
class Threshold(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, threshold=.5):
    super().__init__()
    if threshold < 0.0 or threshold > 1.0:
        raise ValueError("Threshold value must be in [0,1]")
    else:
        self.threshold = threshold

def min_max_fscale(self, input):
    r"""
    applies min max feature scaling to input. Each channel is treated individually.
    input is assumed to be N x C x H x W (one-hot-encoded prediction)
    """
    for i in range(input.shape[0]):
        # N
        for j in range(input.shape[1]):
            # C
            min = torch.min(input[i][j])
            max = torch.max(input[i][j])
            input[i][j] = (input[i][j] - min) / (max - min)
    return input

def forward(self, input):
    assert (len(input.shape) == 4), f"input has wrong number of dims. Must have dim = 4 but has dim {input.shape}"

    input = self.min_max_fscale(input)
    return (input >= self.threshold) * 1.0
```

When I use the function I get the following error, since the gradients are not calculated automatically I assume.

```
Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I already had a look at [How to properly update the weights in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447084/how-to-properly-update-the-weights-in-pytorch) but could not get a clue how to apply it to my case.

How is it possible to calculate the gradients for this function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are manipulating and overwriting elements, this time of operation can't be tracked by autograd. Instead, you should stick with built-in functions. You example is not that tricky to tackle: you are looking to retrieve the minimum and maximum values along `input.shape[0] x input.shape[1]`. Then you will scale your whole tensor in one go *i.e.* in vectorized form. **No *for* loops involved!**

One way to compute min/max along multiple axes is to flatten those:

```
>>> x_f = x.flatten(2)
```

Then, find the min-max on the flattened axis while retaining all shapes:

```
>>> x_min = x_f.min(axis=-1, keepdim=True).values
>>> x_max = x_f.max(axis=-1, keepdim=True).values
```

---

The resulting `min_max_fscale` function would look something like:

```
class Threshold(nn.Module):
    def min_max_fscale(self, x):
        r"""
        Applies min max feature scaling to input. Each channel is treated individually. 
        Input is assumed to be N x C x H x W (one-hot-encoded prediction)
        """
        x_f = x.flatten(2)
        x_min, x_max = x_f.min(-1, True).values, x_f.max(-1, True).values

        x_f = (x_f - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
        return x_f.reshape_as(x)
```

---

##### Important note:

You would notice that you can now backpropagate on `min_max_fscale`... but not on `forward`. This is because you are applying a boolean condition which is not a differentiable operation.